# GNU SCREEN - USB serial tty communication problems with MAC OS X 10.8.2

Tags: macos, serial-port, gnu-screen

we succesfully manage USB to serial communication with a device with Putty on Windows 7 and GNU screen on LINUx but half fail to do so with Terminal / screen on MAC OS.

simple basic communication setup is required on the LINUX windows machine :

> 57600 bps, 8 bits , no parity, no flow control

the device mounts succesfully and is profiled as described here ( sorry in French) :

> Identifiant du produit:    0x6160
>
> Identifiant du fournisseur:    0x03eb  (Atmel Corporation)
>
> Version: 1.10
>
> Vitesse:Jusqu’à 12 Mb/s
>
> Identifiant de l’emplacement:  0x06200000 / 2
>
> Courant disponible (mA):500
>
> Courant requis (mA):0

a cu.usbmodem621 and a tty.usbmodem621 do appear in the list of
ls /dev/tty* or ls /dev/cu*

we activate screen using the following screen command on terminal.app

> screen /dev/tty.usbmodem621 57600

or

> sudo screen  /dev/tty.usbmodem 57600

initally no screenrc file existed, I eventually created one to marginally tune the terminal settings and make sure that there was no flow control :

> defscrollback 5000
>
> termcapinfo xterm* ti@:te@
>
> defflow off
>
> hardstatus alwayslastline "%{rk}%H %{gk}%c %{yk}%M%d %{wk}%?%-Lw%?%{bw}%n*%f %t%?(%u)%?%{wk}%?%+Lw%?"

I have tried without specific drivers, then with the 2 following references

FTDI http://www.ftdichip.com/FTDrivers.htm

Prolific PL2303 http://osx-pl2303.sourceforge.net/

I have also copied and pasted all the settings listed on a 
stty -a 
as per the LINUX machine. Here they are :

> speed 57600 baud; 92 rows; 145 columns;
>
> lflags: icanon isig iexten echo echoe echok echoke -echonl echoctl -echoprt -altwerase -noflsh -tostop -flusho pendin -nokerninfo -extproc
>
> iflags: -istrip icrnl -inlcr -igncr ixon -ixoff ixany imaxbel iutf8 -ignbrk brkint -inpck -ignpar -parmrk
>
> oflags: opost onlcr -oxtabs -onocr -onlret
>
> cflags: cread cs8 -parenb -parodd hupcl -clocal -cstopb -crtscts -dsrflow -dtrflow -mdmbuf
>
> cchars: discard = ^O; dsusp = ^Y; eof = ^D; eol = ;  eol2 = ; erase = ^?; intr = ^C; kill = ^U; lnext = ^V; min = 1; quit = ^\; reprint = ^R; start = ^Q; status = ^T; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; time = 0; werase = ^W;

In ALL cases, the device correctly receives and interprets all commands we send from the screen terminal window but screen fails to display any communication FROM the device.

I have tried Goserial as well a Zterm with the same result.

any hint of what is going on ?

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same problems as your. Have you ever found a solution for this?

Comment: hello @lightxx. no I resigned myself to use a windows machine and putty as a workaround, let us know if you solve it !

Answer (score 2):

Among the [common pitfalls](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/serial-communication/all#common-pitfalls) of serial communication are:

- RX-to-TX, TX-to-RX
- Baud Rate Mismatch
- Bus Contention (such as a getty process; cf. `sudo lsof /dev/tty.usbmodem`)
- Overrun (of chip buffer; occurs when characters come into the serial communication chip too fast)
- Bad Communications Parameters
- Framing errors (BAUD, PARITY, DATA BITS and/or STOP BITS may not be correct)
- Parity errors
- ... (see "Troubleshooting Serial Lines" by cisco)

An alternative to using `screen` would be to use `picocom` / `setserial` or `cu -l /dev/tty.usbmodem -s 9600`  (for troubleshooting purposes).

To get a virtual serial port to troubleshoot `screen` you may use something like:

```
socat GOPEN:/dev/ptyp0,ignoreeof TCP:10.0.1.93:10002
```

Make sure that no flow control (hardware or software) is being used.

For more information on "Setting up a Serial Console in Mac OS X" see [here](http://www.club.cc.cmu.edu/~mdille3/doc/mac_osx_serial_console.html) (e. g. `.plist` file that starts `getty`; `screen /dev/cu.usbserial 115200 8N1`).